# C# solve simplest equations

Tags: c#, solver

In C#, I am looking for a way to solve simple equations like this. `Z = A + B`

I am trying to build a class that would give me the 3rd parameter if I give any of the 2 others.

Example, given `Z=A+B`

If you know `A=3` and `B=6` then you know `Z=9`

If you know `A=4` and `Z=8` then you know `B=4`

How would I best perform these kinds of tasks in software?

The other idea is to use math expressions evaluates, like ncalc. They can interpret math expressions, for example convert `3*(8+2)` into `30`, but not solve equations like `3*(8+x)=30` --> `x=2`.

Comment: @user814064 The question shows that research was done and actually reviewed - there appears to be a misunderstanding about the capabilities of some of the information presented (NCalc appears to meet the OP's requirements) - it's a better question that the nth NullPointerException question for sure

Comment: Question about tools are off-topic.

Comment: It basically boils down to "how do I parse/evaluate expressions with variables?" OP shows research effort and it pretty clearly falls in the category of "a specific programming problem" [On-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thanks a lot jdphenix for not holding my question. Still there are interesting comments/answers made below that could help me find a solution! Best regards!

Comment: To do what you need based on your own requirements, you're basically looking at finding or implementing a computer algebra system with the functions you need. That would be in the "I can only find complicated solvers for quadratic equations, systems of equations, or more complex ones..." category

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure NCalc wouldn't do what you need? Take a look at an example from http://ncalc.codeplex.com/.

> Define parameters, even dynamic or expressions

```
Expression e = new Expression("Round(Pow([Pi], 2) + Pow([Pi2], 2) + [X], 2)");

e.Parameters["Pi2"] = new Expression("Pi * [Pi]");
e.Parameters["X"] = 10;

e.EvaluateParameter += delegate(string name, ParameterArgs args)
  {
    if (name == "Pi")
    args.Result = 3.14;
  };

Debug.Assert(117.07 == e.Evaluate());
```

Please note this is untested - but it looks like you could do something like this with NCalc:

```
var e = new Expression("[A] + [B]"); 
e.Parameters = /* your input */ 
var result = e.Evaluate();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer regarding NCalc. Actually it's not what I'm looking for or I don't understand how to use it. I would like my expression to be "A+B=10", with Parameter[A]=3. The evaluator should then return B=7. (And no I can not turn the equation into evaluating 10-A, with Parameter[A]=3), as the supplied parameter could be either A or B. thanks a lot if you have an idea to tweak Ncalc.

Answer (score -2):

Try out [C# Expression Evaluator](http://csharpeval.codeplex.com/) , See if it matches your requirements.

Comment: link only? Do you have a usage example?

Comment: I didn't use it. Its documentation suggest that C# expression evaluator provides basic arithmetic operations.

Comment: ExpressionEvaluator only compiles a c# (code) expression into a .NET function that can be called repeatedly with different inputs. I think what the OP needs is an expression solver, like [this site uses](http://www.algebra.com/services/rendering/simplifier.mpl). I am the author of ExpressionEvaluator and it seems I get a some traffic from this page.

Comment: This isn't the right answer and you haven't even taken the time to read the link yourself to check, let alone paste a useful snippet.