# How to calculate "23*36/12" get from single textbox in C#

Tags: c#

When I am Convert into Double than compiler gives error

```
Convert.ToDouble(txtFormula.Text);
```

Comment: What error does the compiler give you?

Comment: Do you want to invent a calculator?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674416/c-sharp-solve-simplest-equations

Comment: You should read about expression trees. You could build an expression tree based on the user's input and later calculate the result. I found a nice link that may help you http://www.aboutmycode.com/net-framework/building-expression-evaluator-with-expression-trees-in-csharp-part-1/.

Comment: Nice expression parser here: https://flee.codeplex.com/

Comment: I think My Question Heading is more dark and clear my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `Convert.ToDouble` just converts `string` value to `double` if it's possible;

> Converts the specified string representation of a number to an
>   equivalent double-precision floating-point number.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k(v=vs.110).aspx

and since `"23*36/12"` is not a `double` value representation but a *formula* you have an exception thrown.

If you want to *compute* a simple *formula* you can use, say, [DataTable.Compute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using (DataTable tbl = new DataTable()) {
  double result = tbl.Compute("23*36/12", null);
  ...
}
```